# Python Selenium, webpage continuously refreshes for a random amount of time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to write a Python script that is designed to go to the Bet365 webpage, grab the names of UFC fighters and the odds of upcoming UFC fights, and then write them to a CSV. I was able to do this successfully with another betting site, however, when I try to do this with Bet365, the driver appears to be constantly refreshing for a random amount of time. Sometimes this refreshing goes on for a couple of minutes and sometimes it only lasts for a couple of seconds. Is there something I'm missing in my script, or does it have to do with the website itself?

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)


driver.get("https://www.bet365.com/#/AC/B9/C20511432/D1/E148/F2/")

fightInfo = driver.find_element_by_class_name("sgl-MarketFixtureDetailsLabel")
americanOdds = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("sgl-MarketOddsExpand")
```

Comment: Bet365 is a common site over here that prevents scrapping as much as possible. Try using the undectable chromedriver and see if that helps.

Comment: I could not replicate your issue with the code you provided here.                                     
I tested it in windows 10, python 3.9, Selenium 4 and chrome (95) in pycharm. driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.bet365.com/#/AC/B9/C20511432/D1/E148/F2/")

fightInfo = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "sgl-MarketFixtureDetailsLabel")
americanOdds = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "sgl-MarketOddsExpand")

sleep(60)

Comment: I tried the same script with a chrome driver instead of firefox, and it seemed to work perfectly fine. Not sure what the issue was, but I'm glad it's working as intended now.